# How to transform observable response to return existing object instead of a new object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

This is what i have for now:

```
cachedEntities: Map<string, CareerPreferenceMyCareer> = new Map<string, CareerPreferenceMyCareer>();

getByEmployeeId(employeeId: string): Observable<CareerPreferenceMyCareer> {
    return this.http.get<CareerPreferenceMyCareer>(`${this.startupService.settings.coreUrl}/${this.serviceEndpoint}/ByEmployee/${employeeId}`).pipe(
      map(res => {
        if (res)
          this.cachedEntities.set(employeeId, res); //I want to get exatly this object but map operator creates a new object
        return this.cachedEntities.get(employeeId);
      })
    );
  }
```

I know the new object is created because of `map` pipe operator but is it possible to get the existing object instead of a new object? Maybe with another operator?

I hope to have e explained well my problem. Thanks in advance and correct me if i am wrong with any mistake i have written

Comment: Neither rxjs `map`, nor setting and getting a `Map` entry are creating a new object. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

no. map operator dont create a new object. return exactly the same object. is your function making a new object. See a example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cezdgd